# Setting lifecycle rule on a folder in a google cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud bucket called "life_meaning" I want to set a lifecycle rule on a folder named "42" in the root of the bucket. I want the objects in the bucket to be deleted after 42 days. I set a prefix on object conditions in the rule of `life_meaning/42/`

I feel that this is incorrect should it be `42/` or `42`?

Google docs are a little ambiguous with how this works: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#matchesprefix-suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter “/” argument can be used to restrict the results to only the "files" in the given "folder". Without the delimiter, the entire tree under the prefix is returned.

If you want to delete the objects within the “42” folder., you should set the prefix as "42/".

If you set the prefix to "42" (without the trailing slash) It won't target the items in the "42" folder directly, and it will  apply the lifecycle rule to objects in in other folders that start with "42" in their name